# Declare a single static variable that will be used by many WebMethod functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables, code-behind, webmethod

I have a session variable that I need to use on a cs page with many webmethod functions. If I declare it as follows I don't always get the latest variable. Sometimes it gives me the variable that was stored before the last one. What am I doing wrong?

```
public partial class uc_functions : MyBasePage
{
    static string ucService = HttpContext.Current.Session["ucService"] as string;
....

[WebMethod] //1
[WebMethod] //2
[WebMethod] //3
```

Comment: You need to get this in each webmethod because its value may have changed.

Comment: Does it mean that I have to declare it 20 times? That doesn't make sense to me.... ! Or maybe that's the way it should be.

Comment: No declare it just one time and assign value to it in every webmethod

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently you're initializing the variable *once*, when the class is first loaded. You want to have a different value on each request.

Rather than having a variable for that, you should have a property or method. For example:

```
private static string Service
{
    get { return (string) HttpContext.Current.Session["ucService"]; }
}
```

Or in C# 6:

```
private static string Service => (string) HttpContext.Current.Session["ucService"];
```

(As an aside, I'd review the [.NET naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - a class called `uc_functions` makes me shudder...)

Comment: Plus one for Naming Conventions